# clang. binary operator overloading for nested templates

Tags: c++, templates, clang, operators, c++17

I'm trying to overload binary operator+ for nested template class with clang and got the error `invalid operands to binary expression. Note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument T`. Something like:

```
template<typename T>
class Container
{
  struct Iterator {
    template<typename U>
    friend typename Container<U>::Iterator operator+(size_t, typename Container<U>::Iterator const&);
   };
};

template<typename U>
typename Container<U>::Iterator
operator+(size_t, typename Container<U>::Iterator const&)
{
  return Container<U>::Iterator{};
}
```

Is there way to overload binary operators for nested template class using clang compiler?

C++17 can be used.

Comment: The left side of `::` is an undeduced context. It's not possible to deduce `U`.

Comment: Also, it is far easier to do these sorts of templates inline within the nested class declaration, otherwise you end up needing to do template<typename T> template<typename U>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't make the inner function a template. Just make it a non-template non-member `friend` and define it inline:

```
template<typename T>
class Container
{
  struct Iterator {
    friend Iterator operator+(size_t, Iterator const&) {
      return {};
    } 
  };
};
```

This works in C++11. C++03 if you don't `{}` in the return.